# What could be causing green dollar signs to appear and then freeze my computer?

Tags: graphics-card, gaming, sli

So long story short, I installed a new motherboard, heat sink, and power supply. I had this issue once or twice before on my old motherboard, but only after playing [PAYDAY 2](http://www.crimenet.info/).

But now I’m getting it more frequently. I got it once immediately after pressing “Play” on a YouTube video. I also get it frequently after playing [Red Orchestra 2](http://www.heroesofstalingrad.com). I have two [GeForce NVIDIA 580s](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-580) in an SLI. I think I might know, but does anyone else want to venture what I should call this?

[image: strange error]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some problem with the graphics card driver, the bus or the graphics card itself.

The graphic card works just like a printer, if you try to send raw text to it or any data that doesn't correspond to its protocol, it will print this data in the screen as text. It seems to me you are experiencing something like that.

Try updating the drivers and clean the contacts on the PCI Express slots with a soft rubber and see if it helps.

Make sure your PSU is sufficient to power this graphic card. They are quite demanding, and if the PSU cannot power them properly you will experience issues.

If the problem persists, the card may be defective. Try another card if you have one available, or try your card in another computer to determine where the problem is.